# .apply() throwing TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get length of my fields in `item_description` column and store into new column, but it throws this error `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`

Code:

```
df['desc_len']=df['item_description'].apply(len)
```

When I run it on `name` field (`dtype` for both is `object`) it runs without error.
What am I missing?

`df` is a DataFrame

Comment: print `df['item_description'].head(10)`, it would be helpful.

Comment: That float is generally `nan`. Either check nan's manually or use `str.len` like jezrael mentioned.

Comment: @ayhan Is this a duplicate? Seems like it...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If the question is "why am I getting this error" it is not a duplicate but if it's "how do I accomplish this task" it's a duplicate. What do you think? :)

Comment: @ayhan If it is a "why" then I can swear I've seen _another_ question that would be a suitable dupe... looking for it. So much for trying to elicit more information from OP to make their question actually useful 

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah there are a lot of questions regarding NaNs having no len() but it is hard to find a canonical one as it can appear for everything. Let me know if you can find it.

Comment: @ayhan there are so many garbage questions that actually get answered rather than closed, and it's hard to find a decent duplicate anywhere. Okay, I cannot find it, and I don't want to close it as a duplicate of the above since it doesn't actually answer the question in its entirety.

Comment: Argh I wasn't trying to open chat sorry. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ A clean up is necessary but the tag is so active and I am not sure there will be enough people contributing.

Comment: @ayhan Aha... finally found it...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Congrats. Let me save it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want get `length`s of some iterable like `list`s, use [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) which is more general as `apply(len)`:

```
df['desc_len']=df['item_description'].str.len()
```

Your solution:

```
df['desc_len']=df['item_description'].apply(len)
```

working nice in ideal data - only iterable. But if mix - iterable and scalars it raise error.

Comment: this worked! Why did `.apply()` worked on `name` field and not the other?

Comment: as ayhan mentioned, there are some scalars - obviously `NaN`s .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure .str.len() would work.  I would suggest:

`df['desc_len'] = df['item_description'].apply(str).apply(len)`

Comment: It works, and is faster than this.

Comment: Didn't work for me, hence my suggestion.